# how to scrape link from a previous function with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this code to scrape a website. The `def parse` function gives the full link of a full news, and `def parse_item` returns 3 items which are date, title, and also the full text from the full url.

How can I also scrape and save the link from `def parse`? So the code would return 4 items which are date, title, text, and also the link.

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class weeklymining(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'weeklymining'
    start_urls = ['https://www.miningweekly.com/page/coal/page:'+str(x) for x in range(0,351)]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//*[@class="en-serif"]/a/@href'):
            yield response.follow(
                url=link.get(),
                callback=self.parse_item
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'date': response.xpath('//*[@class="article_title"]//p/span[1]/text()').extract(),
            'title': response.xpath('//*[@id="article_headline"]/text()').get(),
            'text':''.join([x.get().strip() for x in response.xpath('//*[@id="article_content_container"]//p//text()')])
            }
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(weeklymining)
    process.start()
```

Anyhelp would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `response.url` to the yielded item.

For example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class weeklymining(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'weeklymining'
    start_urls = ['https://www.miningweekly.com/page/coal/page:'+str(x) for x in range(0,351)]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//*[@class="en-serif"]/a/@href'):
            yield response.follow(
                url=link.get(),
                callback=self.parse_item
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'date': response.xpath('//*[@class="article_title"]//p/span[1]/text()').extract(),
            'title': response.xpath('//*[@id="article_headline"]/text()').get(),
            'text':''.join([x.get().strip() for x in response.xpath('//*[@id="article_content_container"]//p//text()')]),
            'link': response.url   # <-- added this
            }
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(weeklymining)
    process.start()
```